# How to obtain the bounding ellipse of a target connect component

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, matlab

Suppose we have a connected component in the image as the following image illustrates:[image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92688392/ellipse.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92688392/ellipse.jpg).

My question is how can calculate the bounding ellipse of the connected components (the red ellipse in the image). I have checked MATLAB function [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html), and understand how MATLAB can do that. I also notice that Opencv has similar function to do that [CBlob::GetEllipse()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib/#cvBlobsLib-1). However, although I understand how they obtain the result by reading the code, the fundamental theory behind it is still unclear to me. I am therefore wondering whether there are some standard algorithms to do the job. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, I reorganized my question: in [image moment Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) the calculation formula of the longest axis angle is

[image: formula]

However, in the MATLAB function [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html), the codes are as follows:

```
    % Calculate orientation.
    if (uyy > uxx)
        num = uyy - uxx + sqrt((uyy - uxx)^2 + 4*uxy^2);
        den = 2*uxy;
    else
        num = 2*uxy;
        den = uxx - uyy + sqrt((uxx - uyy)^2 + 4*uxy^2);
    end
```

This implementation is inconsistent with the formula in Wikipedia. I was wondering which one is correct.

Comment: @ High Performance Mark I understand image moment, but I cannot figure out how can I use image moment to calculate the ellipse.For example, how can I link image moment with the major axis of the ellipse? Are there some materials on that topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to find out what's the algorithm behind it as well so I could write my own implementation of it. I found it on a [blog post of mathworks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/30/visualizing-regionprops-ellipse-measurements/). In one of the comments, the author says:

> regionprops calculates the 2nd-order moments of the object in question and then returns measurements of the ellipse with the same 2nd-order moments.

and later later:

> The equations used are from Haralick and Shapiro, Computer and Robot Vision vol. 1, Appendix A, Addison-Wesley 1992. I did a sanity check by constructing an image containing an ellipse with major axis length = 100 and minor axis length = 50, and regionprops returned the correct measurements.

I don't have that book but seems I'll need to get a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a OpenCV implementation than I can give it to you. The algorithm is the following:

1. Convert image to 1bit (b&w)
2. Find all contours
3. Create contour that contains all points from founded contours
4. Calculate convex hull of this contour
5. Find rotated ellipse (rectangle) with minimal square that contains calculated in previous step contour

Here's code:

```
Mat src = imread("ellipse.jpg"), tmp;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Point> bigContour, hull;
RotatedRect ell;

//step 1
cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(tmp, tmp, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

//step 2
findContours(tmp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//step 3
for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    for (size_t j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
    {
        bigContour.push_back(contours[i][j]);
    }
}

//step 4
convexHull(bigContour, hull);

//step 5
ell = fitEllipse(hull);

//drawing result
ellipse(src, ell, Scalar(0,0,255), 2);

imshow("result", src);
waitKey();
```

This is the input:

[image: Input]

And here's a result:

[image: Result image]

Comment: Thanks, and I understand how you did it as well as the idea behind it. However,  MATLAB function [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html) uses a different algorithm. It would be nice if someone can explain that function as detailed as you.

Comment: @feelfree I don't know MATLAB at all, so I can't help you with that. But don't forget that OpenCV is opensource so you can read implementation of any OpenCV's function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how matlab or opencv calculates the ellipsoid. But if you are interested in math behind it, there is a very nice optimization approach called [Löwner-John ellipsoid](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/geom.pdf). You can find more information about this method in the Stanford [Convex  Optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures.html) course. I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, but the theory behind matlab or opencv function is much easier than what you suggested. After reading the codes, I think it relates to image moment. The link between image moment and bounding ellipse is hard to understand for me.